# Initializing a subclass of `Time`

Tags: ruby, time

I want to create a subclass of `Time`, let's say `MyTime`, so that I can define (especially formatting-related) methods without polluting the `Time` class.

```
class MyTime < Time; end
```

For some constructor methods defined on `Time`, I can use them in `MyTime` like this:

```
MyTime.now
```

but sometimes I need to create an instance of `MyTime` based on an instance of `Time`. For example, I would like to have an instance of `MyTime` based on:

```
File.mtime(path_to_some_file)
```

which is a `Time` instance. The constructor `Time#new` does not accept `Time` instances, so I cannot use that. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you use composition instead of inheritance? `MyTime` could simply hold an instance of the `Time` class and delegate all calls to it, this may be a more verbose implementation; but it would allow you the flexibility you desire for `File.mtime(...)`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen If that is the only way to go, that would be the last resort, but if possible, I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Time` class has an [`at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-at) class method that takes a `Time` instance as an argument:

> **at(time) → time**
>   [...]
>
> Creates a new time object with the value given by *time*, [...]

So you can say things like this:

```
>> class MyTime < Time; end
>> mt = MyTime.at(File.mtime(path_to_some_file))
>> mt.class
=> MyTime
```

So converting a `Time` to a `MyTime` is a simple matter of calling `MyTime.at`.